# Docker en windows bash no revela las carpetas existentes en /var/www/html

Tags: windows, bash, docker

Al acceder al directorio `/var/www/html` del contenedor utilizando **bash** no se visualiza una carpeta que efectivamente sí está en los archivos fisicamente. Otra carpeta que también está fisicamente si se visualiza ahí y se puede acceder.

```sh
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/src/public] does not exist
```

Es como si la carpeta no existiera físicamente sabiendo que si está ahí.

Comment: puedes poner ese docker-compose? porque como tal no recuerdo que el framework integre un archivo docker-compose para montar los requisitos... y tampoco tiene un "supervisor" propio...

Comment: no entiendo lo de _y acceder ok al bash_

Comment: te refieres a que no esta fisicamente, o que no esta montado el directorio correspondiente sobre el /var/www/html? ten en cuenta que un docker puede tener copiado o no el contenido que te interese, o puedes sobreescribir la carpeta para que utilice la del host...

Comment: Están fisicamente dos carpetas, una si se muestra y puedo acceder por /www/var/html en la consola y la otra no se revela allí en /var/www/html como si no existiera fisicamente

Comment: Puedes compartir el archivo docker y el comando que ejecutas para correrlo.